# How to show a list of all of the GitHub user's repositories?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, github, django-allauth

I added `django-allauth` to the Django project and I can authentication with GitHub on website.

Right now I have a different task, I want to show a list of all of the GitHub user's repositories on the web page (it will be only repositories of this user).

Do you know how it to do with  `django-allauth` package? 
Or with another package?
Or maybe exist another way?

Comment: using github api you can query for all public repos of a user by github `username`. If they have given access to their private repos too to your github app then you can get private repos too. Endpoint is: [`GET /users/:username/repos`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories), eg.: https://api.github.com/users/vaibhavhrt/repos

Comment: @vaibhav-vishal But if use this API how to get private repos?

Comment: You create a GitHub app with scope of private repos and user needs to grant permission. If using for personal account, create a personal access token with private repo access.

Comment: To add to what @Vaibha Vishal has said, please refer this link to know more about it. May be this link will be helpful for you https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/installations/#list-repositories

Comment: But  GET /users/:username/repos no show all repos, why?

Comment: https://api.github.com/users/jefftriplett/repos - how get all repos?
https://github.com/jefftriplett in API does not a complete list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a `GET` call to their API to get the details of user and their repos.

In your case you can just make a `GET` HTTP request to `https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos`. This will fetch you the JSON object containing list of repos of the user, along with some meta-data for each of the repo.

You can find more about GitHub API [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Comment: But if use this API how to get private repos?